# $(1+x^2)T = 1$ in $\mathscr D'(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: distribution-theory

I only know that the solutions of $xT=0$ in $D'(\mathbb{R})$  are in the form $c\delta_0$, but I can't figure out how to find general solution to $(1+x^2)T = 1$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $f\in C^\infty$ and $fT=0$ in the sense of distributions, then $supp T\subset f^{-1}(\{0\})$, i.e. support of $T$ is a subset of the set of zeroes of $f$.

Second hint: $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\in C^{\infty}(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Here $f$ has no zeros, $suppT$ is the empty set, so the solution to $(1+x^2)T=0$ is $T=0$, correct?
then the general solution is $0 + \frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ ?

Comment: @YassinMarzouki yes, you are right.

Comment: thank you, what if $suppT$ is not an empty set, for example if $f$ is a polynomial with real solutions, what would be the solution? Is there a general rule?

Comment: Suppose $f$ is a polynomial. Then its roots $x_j$ are isolated points. Then, by principle of attachement (principe de recollement in French, don't know the correct name in english) $T$ is a sum of distributions $T_j$ each of them having their support $supp\,T_j=\{x_j\}$. Now you can solve the problem for each $T_j$ separately.

Comment: To continue: for each $T_j$ the problem reduces to finding the solution to $x^kT=0$, which I leave for you to solve (hint: the number of derivatives of $\delta_0$ that you're going to use is somehow related to $k$). Then you take the sum of the obtained solutions. For example $x^2(1-x)T=0$ has solutions $c_0\delta_0+c_1\delta_0'+c_2 \delta_1$.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!

Comment: @YassinMarzouki you are welcome!